# Get max value in Python in case of tiebreaker

Tags: python, max

I would like to know of a way to get the reverse alphabetical order item in the case of a tiebreaker using `max(lst,key=lst.count)` or if there is a better way.

For example if I had the following list:

```
mylist = ['fire','water','water','fire']
```

Even though both water and fire occur twice, I would like it to return `'water'` since it comes first in the reverse alphabetical order instead of it returning the first available value.

Answer (score 0):

I created a function that gets the max value based on two keys, being one primary and one secondary.

Here it is:

```
def max_2_keys(__iter: iter, primary, secondary):
    srtd = sorted(__iter, key=primary, reverse=True)
    filtered = filter(lambda x: primary(x) == primary(srtd[0]), srtd)
    return sorted(filtered, key=secondary, reverse=True)[0]
```

in your case, you can execute the following lines:

````
from string import printable
max_2_keys(lst,primary=lst.count, secondary=lambda x: printable[::-1].index(x[0]))
```
````